# transform sets of key-value rows into database records

Tags: database, key-value

I have to import into a database hundreds of files where data is formatted in this way:

```
key1: value1
key2: value2
...
keyn: valuen
```

Each file contains hundreds of sets with n key:value pairs.
In the database, each key should become a column and its value the field value; each set should become a record.
Which could be the better way?
I apologize in advance if this question replicates another, but I cannot find similar one.

Comment: what is the delimiter for the row and column ?

Comment: In the files there are no rows nor columns, there are only lines containing "key: value" and terminated by newline character.
Each set is separated by three newline characters.

Comment: you want to do it at database level or at front end level

Comment: starting it all as a bunch of files, I'm not sure if dealing with them at database level would be a good solution. I'm thinking more of something like an ETL

Comment: Ok so you can do it with  ssis transformation with flat file as a source.

Comment: Actually that was my first intent. Thank you

Comment: @Reffaelewhich DB you want to load data into .